# How can I use Pygame on atom editor?

Tags: python, pygame, atom-editor

I already installed the latest version of Python 3 and I installed Pygame using the terminal I also included import Pygame in my file however when I run the file it refuses to open and displays the error message "**no module named pygame**"
What's the problem?
What's the solution?

Comment: Have you got the capitalisation correct? Have you installed pygame?

Comment: Using the terminal? you mean, with pip install? A few question maybe help, in wich SO are you working? windows? Linux, Ios? Do you have another version of python installed?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @DamianLattenero yes I used pip3 command and my operating system is Mac OS. I only have python 2 version which is installed by default by OS X

Comment: @Chris no I'm using Mac OS. No virtual environment involved

Comment: Could you add your program.py and how are you executing it?

Comment: @rosh I did the capitalization as the video tutorial instructed ( and it worked for them ) both using Mac OS, the video however is old so maybe it's a new problem? ( I'm not sure about the path that I used in the configuration it was different from the tutorial )

Comment: @DamianLattenero I created a file and saved it as my first.py. it works and the syntax highlights are just fine.

Comment: @DamianLattenero I suspect the problem could have been with the path i put in the configuration. I'm new to paths and directory.

Comment: So, you solved the problem? or still not working?

Comment: @DamianLattenero is there a way to figure out find exactly what my python3 path is? Even better can I manually add python or link it manually to the editor?

Comment: @DamianLattenero can i drag the python 3 file and drop it in the atom editor?

Comment: Why want you do that?

Comment: @DamianLattenero because I don't know how to find the path to my python 3 but it seems your suggestion might help me now, thank you.

Comment: @goldfrappp what bitness have you got, pygame is (officially) only 32 bit and only works with 32 bit versions of python (doesn't matter if using an unofficial pygame with  64bit support)

Comment: @NickA I'm not sure what bitness my python is how can I figure that out?

Comment: @goldfrappp you can run `import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))` in any python version (to my knowledge)

Comment: to see your python path type in a terminal: which python3

Comment: Take a look at this site, might help you with some issues with python 3 in mac http://www.marinamele.com/2014/07/install-python3-on-mac-os-x-and-use-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper.html

Comment: Thank you very much I will look it up

Comment: @NickA I will try that. Though we should be able to know that from the get info button -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `python3 first.py` in your terminal.

Or in your file first.py add this line at the top:
(I used python3.x but you should add the correct version of your python 3)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.x
```

To see your version:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

To see your python 3 path:

```
 $ which python3
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that.

Comment: @goldfrappp you are welcome! let me know if that worked! if it does, don't forget to accept the answer (with the (✓) top left in the answer ;))